# How to setup proxy ARP in linux network namespace?

Tags: linux, networking, arp

I'm running a veth pair - one end in the root namespace(let's call it `inner`), the other(let's call it `outer`) inside a different namespace.

From the namespace I'd like to set up proxy ARP on `outer` interface such that ARP queries for any address inside a given subnet are resolved with the MAC address of `inner`.

I try issuing from the non-root namespace:
`arp -i outer -s 172.44.0.1 22:22:22:22:22:22 netmask 255.255.0.0 pub`

Where `172.44.0.1` is an address from the subnet and `22:22:22:22:22:22` is the MAC address of `inner`.

I get `SIOCSARP: Invalid argument`and I don't understand where the problem comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 1999 and kernel series 2.2 or so, it hasn't been possible to add `pub` arp entries with a netmask; see e.g. [this mailing list thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-net@vger.rutgers.edu/msg04162.html).

You'd have to add individual proxyarp entries to your arp table (which feels kludgy with a /16 netmask), or enable proxyarp on the entire interface via `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/outer/proxy_arp`, which will then cause your box to reply to *all* arp queries for destinations it has a route for, provided that destination is not towards the `outer` interface.

You may be able to get where you want to be with [parprouted](https://linux.die.net/man/8/parprouted); I have yet to try it.